# Locale-specific default settings in XCode / iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, settings

I have an iPhone application with a Settings.bundle. This bundle has items with defaults that must be locale-dependent (ex: "Metric Units" must be "off" for US and "on" for Brazil and such).

Is there anyway to keep settings' defaults locale-dependent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem some days ago. From what I know it is impossible to have different default values for different regions so I solved it in a different way.

I have a multi-value setting with `Default` `Fahrenheit` and `Celsius`. By default it is set to default, which means that I figure out the unit in code based on the NSLocale setting

Something like this:

```
- (MBUnit)temperatureUnit {
    MBUnit tmp = [ud integerForKey:MBUDKeyTemperatureUnit];
    if (tmp == MBTemperatureDefaultUnit) {
        MBUnit defaultTemperatureUnit;
        BOOL isMetric = [[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem] boolValue];
        if (isMetric) {
            defaultTemperatureUnit = MBTemperatureCelsiusUnit;
        }
        else {
            defaultTemperatureUnit = MBTemperatureFahrenheitUnit;
        }
        return defaultTemperatureUnit;
    }
    return [ud integerForKey:MBUDKeyTemperatureUnit];
}
```

Comment: Too bad I can't do it, but I really loved the "Default" idea! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at stringsTable? You may be able to use that for your purpose. Also check out [this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000005-SW1)

What you certainly can do, is set the defaults when the app is first launched (or when the locale changes, for that matter).

Comment: Translation of "Metric Units" using stringsTable was easy, but changing default based on locale isn't. I could set it by hand, but will lead to a minor bug when user opens Settings BEFORE opening my application for the first time (I've done this with Nike+iPod when I brought my iPod).

Comment: What where your problems, exactly? Can you not use the fact that strings are locale-dependent to control other, non-string settings?

Comment: I have a setting named "Metric Unit", an ON/OFF switch. When "ON", app will use km, kg, etc. When "OFF", feets, lbl, etc. I want to make it "ON" by default on countries that use metric system.